# how to get a background div for a element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If a div(handler) is positioned on a top a div(grid cells) then how can we get our div's background div(grid cell)

```
<div class='range-handler'>
  <div class='left-top-handler'></div>
  <div class='right-bottom-handler'></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What you mean by background ```div``` here in this code mentioned? Which div you need to get here?

Comment: For a right bottom circle it will be cell of (5 th row 3 rd column). U can refer image attached.

Comment: If I understood your query, you want to access dynamic div class created at run time, you can create dynamic class for each row, column pair, with a combination that you you would know when you want to read. every time for each cell div class name should be unique. div class name example: 0-0, 0-1, 1-0 etc in this case you will have unique cell position mapped with the css class type and easily readable.

Comment: at run time I want the cell div behind the circle. actually it is a resizing handler in another layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to get div's background div, you must use javascript.

Using `document.querySelector` to get the target. And then, you can use `target.parentElement` to get its parent dom, or use `target.children` to get all his children.

Comment: The handler circle and cells are not having parent child exclusive realtionship. Those are just in 2 seperate layers

Comment: Sorry! I cannot imagine your describe situation. Why not attach a live demo to help us to undestand.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate for that is you can get element by screen coordinates,

```
const touch = event.changedTouches[ 0 ];
document.elementFromPoint( touch.clientX, touch.clientY )
```